# Calculation of dynamic threshold for anomaly detection

Tags: threshold, anomaly-detection, adaptive-threshold

I am a beginner in python and data analyst field. I have timeseries data for example as given below, I have multiple sets of data. Want to find anomalies on the timeseries data we have, for that I am using PYCARET library as it has multiple for anomaly detection but different data requires different threshold, I am unable to find a way through which we can calculate threshold and set the fraction according to it.

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2022-01-02 | 200 |

I want to create a way through which we can find a dynamic threshold which we can calculate and update every time data change takes place. In Pycaret fractions needs to be updated every time for different data so that we can find the correct anomalies.